# Making it day/night in a java game(light/dark)

Tags: java, game-physics

I'm currently building a game in java for fun and educational purposes. It is a 2d tilebased game. The rendering is done pixel by pixel through rgb values.
I do not use any libraries/game engines currently.

I have however run into problem that lies beyond my basic knowledge of java programming. I intend to add a day/night cycle but realised that I had no idea how to add lighting in to a game. 
I am thinking that tweaking the rgb values might be an option, but i do not know if that is viable or how it would be done.

So, is it possible to add lighting/darkness to the game without an engine or use of libraries  (if so, then how would this be done)?

Comment: We don't make library recommendations.  In the future, please omit that part of your question.

Comment: Okay. Thank you, i was not aware of that.

Comment: If it's just a rough pixel by pixel (I'm thinking old style 8 bit) themed game, then I'd just make the sky blue in the day (with a sun) and black in the night (with stars.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at RGB color model: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model

In summary, you have three color channels (Red, Green, Blue) and the higher each color channel value the brigther the color is.

So you can create a darker color by separating the color channels, reducing their values by some amount and recombine the channels to RGB:

```
public static int muchDarker(int rgb) {
    int r = (rgb >> 16) & 255;   // red
    int g = (rgb >> 8) & 255;    // green
    int b = rgb & 255;           // blue
    // now reduce brightness of all channels to 1/3
    r /= 3;
    g /= 3;
    b /= 3;
    // recombine channels and return
    return (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
}
```

Comment: @user3449125 and what's that, code you didn't have to write yourself?

Comment: @NathanTempelman I was not aware of the ability to split up the values(or how to do it) and thereby darken the image. Writing 10 lines of code was not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're drawing individual pixels with RGB values, an easy way to make it dark is to create a filter of sorts.

You can scale the "brightness" of a color by multiplying it's rgb values by a constant. Less than 1 for darker, more than 1 for lighter.

So if you had the bright red color (240, 10, 10), you can make it "night mode" by multiplying all the RGB components by .5, giving you a darker red (120, 5,5). If you look these values up in a RGB color picker, you can see that they're the same color, just different shades.